# Where to place countdown timer code?

Tags: ios, swift, timer, countdown

I'm developing an iOS quiz app and every time a question is asked I want a countdown timer of 15 seconds to start. If the user doesn't answer the question by the time the counter hits zero the answer is considered wrong. My question is where would I place the countdown timer code to make sure everytime a question is asked it gives the user 15 seconds to answer? I also want this time to reset every time a new question is asked.

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //countdown timer
    @IBOutlet weak var questionTimer: UILabel!

    func randomQuestion() {
        //random question
        if questionList.isEmpty {
            questionList = Array(QADictionary.keys)
        }

        let rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questionList.count)))
        questionLabel.text = questionList[rand]

        //matching answer values to go with question keys
        var choices = QADictionary[questionList[rand]]!

        questionList.remove(at: rand)

        //create button
        var button:UIButton = UIButton()

        //variables
        var x = 1
        rightAnswerBox = arc4random_uniform(4)+1

        for index in 1...4
        {
            button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton

            if (index == Int(rightAnswerBox))
            {
                button.setTitle(choices[0], for: .normal)
            }
            else {
                button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
                x += 1
            }

            randomImage()

        }
    }

    let QADictionary = ["Who is Thor's brother?" : ["Atum", "Loki", "Red Norvell", "Kevin Masterson"], "What is the name of Thor's hammer?" : ["Mjolinr", "Uru", "Stormbreaker", "Thundara"], "Who is the father of Thor?" : ["Odin", "Sif", "Heimdall", "Balder"]]

    //wrong view segue
    func wrongSeg() {
       performSegue(withIdentifier: "wrongViewSegue", sender: self)
    }

    //proceed screen
    func rightSeg() {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "rightSeg", sender: self)
    }

    //variables
    var rightAnswerBox:UInt32 = 0
    var index = 0

    //Question Label
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    //Answer Button
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerBox))
        {
            print ("Correct!")
        }
        else if (sender.tag != Int(rightAnswerBox)) {
            wrongSeg()
            print ("Wrong!")
            questionList = []
        }

        randomQuestion()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        randomQuestion()
    }

    //variables
    var seconds = 15
    var timer = Timer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you some basic building blocks to build your solution.

```
// Timer property
var timer: Timer?


// Call this when a new question is loaded
func startTimer() {

    self.timer?.invalidate()

    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 15.0,
                                      repeats: false,
                                      block: { timer in

                                        // Put whatever code should happen if the user does not answer the question in time. 

    })
    RunLoop.main.add(timer,
                     forMode: .commonModes)

}

// Call this when a question has been answered
func questionAnswered() {

    self.timer?.invalidate()

    // Put whatever should happen if a question was answered in time here

}
```